# calculating the area resulting from the intersection of two semicircles.

Tags: calculus

I want to calculate the area resulting from the intersection of two circles. The two circles are congruent with a radius of $1$. The diameter of one circle lies on the x-axis, while the diameter of the other lies on the y-axis. 
I tried solving this by integrating and subtracting the areas I found from one another, but when I try to integrate the area made by the circle which has its diameter on the y-axis, I get imaginary values which does not make sense to me.

The integral I arrived at which gave imaginary values is this $$\int \left(1-\sqrt{1-x^2} \right) dx$$ and I tried to evaluated from $0$ to $(1+\sqrt{7})/2$ which is the value I got from solving the two equations of the circles. Where might I have gone wrong?

[image: I want this shaded area]

Comment: Can't you use geometry instead?

Comment: I think you need to check your limits of integration. They should be from 0 to 1.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I would like to know how to solve it with geometry too!

Comment: @Vasya You're correct! Thanks!

Comment: You subtract the area of the triangle from the area of the sector to find half of the required area. $r=1$ and $\theta=\frac {\pi}2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circle with the diameter on the $y$-axis will have the equation $$x^2+(y-1)^2=1\implies y=1-\sqrt{1-x^2}.$$

The circle with the diameter on the $x$-axis will have the equation $$(x-1)^2+y^2=1\implies y=\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}=\sqrt{2x-x^2}.$$

The two circles intersect at $x=0$ and $x=1$.  The integral you want to evaluate will be $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{2x-x^2}-(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})\,dx.$$

This can be written as the sum of three integrals.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you!